# C# StackOverFlowException when creating new instance of class

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-overflow, instance

Hm i get a strange problem. when i creating new instance of class i get StackOverflowExcepion :)

Here is code:

```
public partial class PlayerChooser : Window
{
public PlayerChooser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBoxPlayer1Name.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        textBoxPlayer2Name.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        textBoxPlayer3Name.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        textBoxPlayer4Name.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }

    public static String player1Name;
    public static String player2Name;
    public static String player3Name;
    public static String player4Name;
    ...

    PlayerChooser.player1Name = textBoxPlayer1Name.Text;
    PlayerChooser.player2Name = textBoxPlayer2Name.Text;
    TwoPlayers501_new twoPlayers501_new = new TwoPlayers501_new();
    twoPlayers501_new.Show();
    ...
}
```

and class and constructor where exception occurs

```
public partial class TwoPlayers501_new : Window
{
    public TwoPlayers501_new()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBlockPlayer1Name.Text = PlayerChooser.player1Name;
        textBlockPlayer2Name.Text = PlayerChooser.player2Name;
    }
    ...
}
```

thanx in advance, it is probably some kind of triviality...

Comment: What does your stack trace look like when the exception occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find out what the hell is wrong with my program. Something went wrong with C# compiler I guess. Because when i removed underscore from class name (now is TwoPlayers504New) everything started working properly.

Thanks a lot Microsoft.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have an event handler somewhere performing an action that changes one of those properties based on the property having been changed?

Short version:  There isn't enough information here to debug your problem.

Suggestion:  Debug your program and when you get the stackoverflowexception, check out the callstack.  I suspect that there's a method or series of methods that cycle infinitely in your stack.

Comment: no those values are entered once, and only used afterwards, never changed.

i tried to put textblocks under comments, like this
 public TwoPlayers501_new()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //textBlockPlayer1Name.Text = PlayerChooser.player1Name;
        //textBlockPlayer2Name.Text = PlayerChooser.player2Name;
    }

and same thing occurs.

Comment: What's your stacktrace look like on the stackoverflow exception?

Comment: [External Code]  
PikadoRacunaljka.exe!Pikado_Racunaljka.TwoPlayers501_new.TwoPlayers501_new() Line 32 C#

and this repeat until stack is overflown. 

Line 32 is

textBlockPlayer1Name.Text = PlayerChooser.player1Name;

Answer (score 0):

You are recursing on yourself:

```
PlayerChooser.player1Name = textBoxPlayer1Name.Text;
PlayerChooser.player2Name = textBoxPlayer2Name.Text;

textBlockPlayer1Name.Text = PlayerChooser.player1Name;
textBlockPlayer2Name.Text = PlayerChooser.player2Name;
```

Comment: no i am not, there is textBoxPlayer1Name.Text and textBlockPlayer1Name.Text
 TextBox, and TextBlock

Comment: How is this recursion?  `int a = b; b = a;` doesn't recurse.